# Heterogeneous reference equality in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

In GHC, the equality instance for `IORef` and `STRef` are based on the following primitive operation:

```hs
sameMutVar# :: MutVar# s a -> MutVar# s a -> Int#
```

I would like to be able to compute a heterogeneous reference equality,

```
sameReference :: IORef a -> IORef b -> Bool
```

(or similarly for `STRef`s with potentially different types). Is it okay to just use `unsafeCoerce` for the purpose of checking the reference equality? Is there a reason that `sameMutVar#` is not given a heterogenous type signature?

EDIT: To add some context, I would like to have this hetereogenous pointer equality because I want to use the equality method to remove a particular `IORef a` from a list of `IORef`s whose types are existentially quantified over.

Comment: Can you use `StableName` and [`eqStableName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html#v:eqStableName) instead?

Comment: Should be safe... In fact, I'm a bit surprised there isn't an `unsafeCoerceMutVar# :: MutVar# s a -> MutVar# s b`...

Comment: I think it would be possible to admit as a primitive `sameRef :: IORef a -> IORef b -> Maybe (a :~: b)` since if the references are equal, then the types must be the same. I'd expect unsafe coercions could actually be safe in this case, but I can't back this up.

Comment: @chi I don't think so. Remember the classic `polyRef :: IORef [a]; polyRef = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef []; unsafeCoerce :: a -> IO b; unsafeCoerce x = writeIORef polyRef [x] >> head <$> readIORef polyRef`. Granted, I feel this behavior is a mistake: `polyRef` is a *function*; the two occurrences in `unsafeCoerce` should be different `IORef`s, and your `sameRef` should be fine. However, I'm not in charge, so, in the current situation, your `sameRef` is probably not the best idea. The `Bool` version seems OK, however.

Comment: @HTNW Yes, polymorphic references already break type safety, using `unsafePerformIO`. I can't see how my `sameRef` would make things worse in such scenario. Arguably, using polymorphic references you can _define_ my `sameRef` without taking it as a primitive, by coercing `IORef b` to `IORef a`, to that it can be compared with the other `IORef a`. Unless there's some issue with safe code, I'd still prefer `safeRef` to return `Maybe (a :~: b)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thanks, I was not aware of `StableName`. However, I am indeed using mutable data, so adding an additional layer of indirection with `StableName` would be less  than ideal.

Comment: @HTNW Do you have an example where `sameRef` would be bad even without `unsafePerformIO`? It feels a bit weird to claim that feature X breaks things in the presence of `unsafePerformIO`, since it's almost never actually feature X's fault.

Comment: @chi, in this case, plain old safe `coerce` is enough to break everything. `oops :: Coercible a b => IORef a -> a :~: b; oops ref = fromJust (sameRef ref (coerce ref))`.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, that's an excellent point, thanks! I guess it should be something like `sameRef :: ... -> Maybe (Dict (Coercible a b))` then. (Or changing the role of `IORef`'s argument, but that's probably overkill). Still, my point is that I'd rather get a `Maybe SomeProof` than a boring boolean, if possible.

Comment: @chi, I *think* that would be safe. You'd surely want `Coercion a b` rather than `Dict (Coercible a b)`, but that's a minor quibble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to write

```
sameReference :: IORef a -> IORef b -> Bool
sameReference = unsafeCoerce ((==) :: IORef a -> IORef a -> Bool)
```

It would have been entirely reasonable for the primop to have been given type

```
sameMutVar# :: MutVar# s a -> MutVar# s b -> Int#
```

but the designers apparently felt that using that function on references of different types was more likely to be a mistake than otherwise.

What you *can't* do safely is conclude that `sameReference (r1 :: IORef a) (r2 :: IORef b) = True` implies that `a` and `b` are the same. Suppose you had

```
sameRefSameType :: IORef a -> IORef b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
```

Then you could easily write

```
oops :: Coercible a b => IORef a -> a :~: b
oops r = fromJust (sameRefSameType r (coerce r))
```

producing bogus evidence that any two coercible types are equal. You should be able to figure out how to use a GADT to get from there to `mkUC :: IO (a -> b)`.

I *believe* that it would be safe to write

```
sameRefCoercibleTypes :: IORef a -> IORef b -> Maybe (Coercion a b)
```

Since Daniel Wagner mentioned stable names, I should mention that the situation for those is even worse in this context. I'll need to start with a bit of background. Suppose you write

```
f :: Either x Int -> Either x Bool
f (Left x) = Left x
f (Right _) = Right False
```

In the first case, it would be a shame to allocate a fresh `Left` constructor just to change the type. So GHC has a low-level optimization (after the core-to-core optimization pipeline) that tries to turn this into (essentially)

```
f p@(Left x) = unsafeCoerce p
f (Right _) = Right False
```

That means that you could have `m :: Either x a` and `n :: Either x b` where `m` and `n` refer to the same heap object despite `a` and `b` having completely unrelated types. If you create a stable name for `m` and a stable name for `n`, then those stable names will compare equal! If you posit even as much as

```
sameSNCoercibleTypes
  :: StableName a
  -> StableName b
  -> Maybe (Coercion a b)
```

then you can use `m` and `n` to "prove" `Coercible (Either x a) (Either x b)` from which you can convert any `a` into any `b`. It's a bit delicate, but since it's possible at all, assuming otherwise is rather unsafe.

Comment: The last part about the low-level optimization is a bit scary, but OTOH it's good to know that the runtime can allow values of different type to share their representation.

Comment: I suggested `StableName` because the `StableName` API *already* offers heterogeneous equality via `eqStableName :: StableName a -> StableName b -> Bool`. So getting a `Bool` out (rather than your proposed coercion) can't be *that* dangerous.